# Grouping by column and calculating percentage, windows function partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following example table "invoices".

```
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| invoice_number | date        | status |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 1              | 2 apr 2021  | 1      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 2              | 9 apr 2021  | 0      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 3              | 9 apr 2021  | 1      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 4              | 9 apr 2021  | 1      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 5              | 16 apr 2021 | 1      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 6              | 16 apr 2021 | 0      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 7              | 16 apr 2021 | 0      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 8              | 16 apr 2021 | 0      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| 9              | 16 apr 2021 | 1      |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
```

(in status, 1 is for paid, 0 for unpaid)
and from it I'm trying to get the following:

- the number of invoices per week (each date is a week so a group per date works)
- the percentage of these invoices that were paid (grouped by date)

I was trying to use a window function to organize better (since I have several more fields, this is just simplified for the example)

and I was doing

```
select date,
       count(invoice_number) over (partition by date) as NumberOfInvoices,
       (sum(status)/count(status) over (partition by date))*100 as percentagePaid
from invoices
```

but of course this is not working,  at the same time I'm getting all the rows for the table as result, instead of them grouped by date.

should I stop trying to use the over partition by here? or am I just applying it incorrectly for what I need?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the percentage of these invoices that were paid (grouped by date)

This would simply be aggregation:

```
select date, avg(status * 1.0) as paid_ratio
from invoices i
group by date;
```

If you wanted this *per row*, then you would use window functions:

```
select i.*,
       avg(i.status * 1.0) over (partition by i.date) as paid_ratio
from invoices i;
```

Note the `* 1.0`.  SQL Server does integer division -- and averages -- on integers.  `status` looks like an integer, so the `* 1.0` converts it to a number with decimal places.

Comment: jez that was fast! thank you! yes, I think I'll do it with aggregation here, one question, the average here works if I have only 1 and 0 as it's averaging over the total grouped by, right?

if I had for example other status such as 2 for rejected and 3 for corrected, I could use a CASE for converting these into 1 and 0 so I could use the average?

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . Yes, `case` is often used:  `avg(case when status = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end)`.

Comment: thank you very much, this solved all my issues here :)   btw, off topic, where do you recommend getting your book from Europe? (that you receive better percentage deal)

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . I would expect it to be available in Amazon or any other online bookstore.